# Template specialization with Parameter Packs

Tags: c++, template-specialization, parameter-pack

I'm quite new to c++ but wanted to try to do some fancy template stuff. I am not sure if it is possible, but I am fairly confident there is a way to achieve that.

So here's the Issue:
I am calling various Hardware function, which requires a number of parameters and only differ by one parameter type:

```
int Read(HANDLE handle, int location, char* Name, int startindex1, int endindex1,
         int startindex2, int endindex2, int* rval, Astruct* callback) ;
int Read(HANDLE handle, int location, char* Name, int startindex1, int endindex1,
         int startindex2, int endindex2, double* rval, Astruct* callback) ;
```

The Hardware Interface returns a scalar, array or matrix, depending on the values of the indexes. What i actually want to achieve, is a function, which returns an `T` or `vector<T>` or `vector<vector<T>>` dependening on the number of parameters I pass.:

```
                T MyReadFunction<T>(HANDLE handle, int location, char* Name,int index)
        vector<T> MyReadFunction<T>(HANDLE handle, int location, char* Name,int startindex1,
                                                                            int endindex1   )
vector<vector<T>> MyReadFunction<T>(HANDLE handle, int location, char* Name,int startindex1, 
                                                                            int endindex1
                                                                            int startindex2, 
                                                                            int endindex2)
```

where `T` is a basic type like `int`, `real`, `float`, `double`,etc.

Using 3 different templates with specializations is no issue, but I would love to combine it somehow.

My assumption is, that this can be achieve using template specializations, but I cant get my head around it. I think i should something like this:

```
template<typename T ,int... Indexes>
T MyReadFunction (HANDLE handle, int location, char* Name, Indexes... myIndex){}

template<>
int MyReadFunction (HANDLE handle, int location, char* Name, int myindex)
{
    int rval = 0; 
    Read (handle,location,name,myindex,myindey,0,0,&rval, NULL) ;
    return rval;
}
```

This comes as a two headed beast. I porperbly need to implement my 3 cases explicitly to avoid misusage, but also want to know, how i could achieve template specialization with variying size of the parameter pack, depending on the size of the pack.

I'am using msvc++ latest with VS 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a type that creates a nested vector of the desired rank, like this:

```
template<typename T,int N> 
struct VT 
{ 
    using type = typename std::vector<typename VT<T, N - 1>::type>;
};

template<typename T> 
struct VT<T, 0> 
{ 
    using type = int;
};
```

and then write a single function like this:

```
template<typename T ,typename ...Indexes>
typename VT<T, sizeof...(Indexes) / 2>::type 
  MyReadFunction (int handle, int location, char* Name, Indexes... myIndex) {}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/99zf17).

As you've observed, there's not really much point in doing this, because the body of the function would become rather tricky to implement. Simply writing specializations, or overloads, would be a simpler solution.

Note that if you do choose the write this function template, the `myIndex` parameter pack is unconstrained, i.e. it will accept types other than `int`. Of course, you can constrain that by writing just a little more code.

Also, this function template will accept `Indexes` of size 3, 5, 7, etc, which is likely not what you want. Again, you can constrain that as well by writing a little more code.

Comment: Worth mentioning that parameter packs always vary in type. `typename ... Indexes` differs from `int ... Indexes` as in the question.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Good point, added some explanation about that.

Comment: I borrowed from your answer to make another one. I avoided packs in favor of a variadic array. By the way, the dimensionality appears to be (the floor of) `sizeof ... Indexes / 2`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Ah, nice catch about the dimensionality. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

cigien has a good answer for this question about parameter packs.

Here's another solution that doesn't use packs. Parameter packs are type-lists, but you don't actually need to vary over N types, you just want an N-dimensional array.

If you put the list of indexes inside curly braces, then you can treat it as a list with compile-time length.

It looks to me, though, like the scalar case may not generalize well from the multidimensional cases. The scalar case takes a single index, whereas the arrays need start and end indexes for each dimension.

```
template<typename T,int N> 
struct VT 
{
    using type = typename std::vector<typename VT<T, N - 1>::type>;
};

template<typename T> 
struct VT<T, 0> 
{ 
    using type = T;
};

template< typename T, int n >
std::enable_if_t< n == 1 || n % 2 == 0,
  typename VT<T, n/2>::type >
  MyReadFunction( HANDLE handle, int location, char* Name, int const (&indexes)[n] );

// usage: MyReadFunction< double >( inputFile, 123, "name", { 1, 2, 3, 4 } );
// yields vector< vector< double > >
```

Comment: Nice answer, and it *looks* correct, but I'm always a little hesitant to UV when there might be a typo or something. Would you care to add a demo? You can use mine, the test cases are fixed now.